# localytics push redirection from inside the application

Tags: android, push-notification, localytics

"Localytics provides a push having deeplink url and we are just storing it in database, 
We have a inbox screen where we shows list of Push received, On tap of Push we want to redirect user to the intended screen.

Now problem is that by using this deeplink url how can we get the actual url behind this deeplink url on the inbox screen, so that we can navigate user to respective screen. because in general implementation when we click on deeplink url outside the application, application open and we get converted url using GoogleApi client on Splash screen"